# NSFetchedResultsController not calling didChangeObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I should start by saying that this all works great when I deploy a debug build to my device directly from xcode.  I only see this problem when I build a signed release IPA.

I have the following fetched results controller:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [MyEntity MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"date"
                                                       ascending:NO
                                                   withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sync == YES"]
                                                         groupBy:nil
                                                        delegate:self
                                                       inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
```

Then implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id) anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) newIndexPath {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: {
            NSLog(@"something was inserted");
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            NSLog(@"something was updated");
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is how I create a new object:

```
// create the new context
self.managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_newMainQueueContext];

// setup default managed object context as parent
self.managedObjectContext.parentContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];

// Create new object
MyEntity *entity = [MyEntity MR_createEntityInContext:self.mangedObjectContext];

// set some properties
entity.sync = YES;  // important one, should be picked up my FRC
...

// save it
[self.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"saved the entity: %@", entity);
}];
```

Again this works when deployed via xcode.  So assuming that I am doing everything right is there something different about a release version that would cause this to not work?  Something about CoreData or MagicalRecord in a release version?

I am stuck as I do not see the didChangeObject fire when watching the logs in the release version, but works just fine in debug version.  Ideas???

Comment: Too many contexts, also typo when creating entity

Comment: @Andy How is this too many contexts? Its 2.  The default context, and when I create a new entity I create a MOC and set its parent to the default context.  If there was a typo sorry about that.

Comment: You use `self.mangedObjectContext` when you call `MR_createEntityInContext`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I personally had deadlocks when using main context to main context relationship with MagicalRecord. Is there really a point in that?

If you want a separate main thread context you can always hook it up with `MR_rootSavingContext` and listen for changes on root context then merge them back manually upon `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. This is exactly how rootContext and defaultContext are configured in MagicalRecord.

I do not suggest `MR_mergeChangesOnMainThread` because it caused too many deadlocks in my experience and not much of attention from maintainers.

The simplest way that I usually take when I use MagicalRecord with FRC is to use `MR_defaultContext` to display data on UI thread and create/save entities in background MOC, i.e:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    MyEntity *entity = [MyEntity MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];

    entity.sync = YES;
} completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
   // check for errors
}];
```

Comment: The only reason I am using a different context is that I need a place to store data that is being filled out.  If the user cancels then I throw away the context.  If they save then MR handles merging it back into the root context.  So from your suggestion you think its better to put data into a different object (not an entity), then transfer the data to an entity if they save?

Comment: If you want a temp context then set parent to root context and merge contexts in NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification. Your FRC then should use your temp main queue context too. You don't need default context here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  I have my FRC attached to the default context as I don't want "temp" (not saved) entities to be picked up by the FRC.  If I set parent to root context instead of the default won't MagicalRecord handle the merge?  And once merged won't it propagate down to the default context?

Comment: Cheers! MagicalRecord will merge any changes on root context into default context automatically. But it won't do that for your main queue context. If you care about changes happening outside you have to do it manually.